# R: Comparing all numbers in a list to themselves and return a matrix of TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r, matrix, equality-operator

Hi all I have numerical vector `x <- c(1,2,3,3)`

and I want to compare all numbers to each other and return a 4 x 4 matrix of TRUE and FALSE indicating if they are identical or not.

Tried to use loops but have not been successful:

```
matx <- matrix(FALSE,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(x))
for(i in nrow(matx)) {
  for (j in ncol(matx)) {
    matx[x==x[i],] <- TRUE
  }
}
```

Comment: show us the loops that didn't work

Comment: `matx<-matrix(FALSE,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(x))
for(i in nrow(matg1)){
  for (j in ncol(matx)){
    matg1[x==x[i],]<-TRUE
  }
}`

Comment: sorry, I need to learn how to post these code chucks!

Comment: edit the question and put them in there. code is illegible in comments

Comment: `matx` or `matg1`? `Error in g1.new : object 'g1.new' not found` Please fix your code example. Don't post broken code without testing it. Are you copying someone else's code? Are you plagiarizing homework?

Comment: ok edited.. thanks. no plagiarising happening, I swear, just tired!

Comment: no no no! don't accept my answer. `outer` is what you should do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer` is clearly the way to go. But if you want to use a loop, you need to define your iterators correctly:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,3)
N <- length(x)
comp = matrix(, nrow=N, ncol=N)

for(i in 1:N) {
    for(j in 1:N) {
        comp[i, j] = (x[i] == x[j])
    }
}
comp

TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `outer` is what you're looking for.  Specifically,

```
outer(x, x, `==`)
```